# Drawing on canvas HTML-Element shown in Android WebView: always lines from bottom to his touch are drawn

Tags: android, canvas, webview, drawing

I have a website with a signature field in it, where the user needs to paint his signature.
On Google Chrome, on Firefox Mobile  and on Safari Mobile - iPhone and iPod Touch- it looks like it should be:

[image: Signature OK]

But on the built in Android browser, and my custom WebView I needed to built for our app, it looks like:
[image: Signature NOT OK]

The Code on the website is:

```
<canvas height="120" width="410"></canvas>   
<input ...
```

I presumed a problem with focusing the webview, but

> ```
> webView.setFocusable(true);
> webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
> webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
> ```

was not solving this.

Have you experienced such behaviour and know a solution? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the website and javascript code with the signature pad on the customer side.
After using the new version of https://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad , the behaviour on Android WebView and the built-in Android browser was fixed.